# Nuxt 3 can't find image after building server

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

When I do an `npm run build` Nuxt generates the server, but images from certain libraries are not found

[image: Nuxt dev mode]

This is from nuxt in dev mode

[image: Nuxt server]

And this is from nuxt built server

The image is from leaflet library so I guess leaflet is not SSR ready but I think there should be a way to fix it

Comment: How do you import the image in your code?

Comment: It is automatic since it is from a library

Comment: And it's not present in the final build? No issues regarding that one on project's github issues?

Comment: No, and in their GitHub they only handle bugs in "vanilla" Leaflet, so I think their library is not ready for SSR

Comment: Use it in `client-only` so. Not like there is any benefit to use it as SSR anyway.

Comment: You mean the whole project? Because the route where that image is shown is already in client side 

Comment: The whole leaflet part doesn't have any benefit being SSR'ed. If you have a full-screen map, so yeah the full path.

Comment: But that route is actually client side since I need to leaflet to use `window` object

Comment: So code, context or [repro] looks to be required to proceed further.